# How tu update repository after branch pull with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, pull

When I create a new branch with Mercurial, I'm able to pull only that certain branch with :

```
hg pull -b <branchname>
```

The console prints the number of the files that had been modified, so not a problem with this.

But when I do :

```
hg update
```

The repository is not updated and so I have to merge this new branch and return to "default" branch in order to have these updates.

please what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

`hg update` will update your repository to the tip of the *current* branch, not to the tip of the repo.

After the pull of a new branch with new changesets, your current repo is assumably updated on another branch, so you can either do

```
hg update tip
```

Or better

```
hg update <branchname>
```